# toggleClass not animating

Tags: jquery, html, css

View this at mobile size (google inspect iPhone 6) as it doesn't get displayed until it hits a breakpoint.

I have a max-height set on one class and then I'm adding another class with a larger max-height !important to ".sectionTwo" using .toggleClass.

It doesn't seem to be animating the height though, how do i fix this?

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sectionTwoBtn").click(function(){
        $(".sectionTwo").toggleClass( "fullHeight", 10000);
        $(".hiddenFade").toggleClass("hideThis", 10000);
    });
});
</script>
```

This is set up to run on the first "Read more" button.

Here is a link to the page: http://go.mmsg.com.au/authoring-sp.html

Thankyou!

Comment: Does it have something to do with jquery not animating max-height?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove 10000, it is working with toggle() but not with toggleClass()

Comment: Removing the 10000 with toggleClass doesn't change anything.

With toggle() it makes the entire div ".sectionTwo" disappear.